# Imported module was not found?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-venv

I am building a web scraper and I am trying to import the 'requests' package but I am getting an error. I am being told the following:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Full Error:

```
(venv) USERs-MacBook-Pro:Scraper user$ /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /Users/user/git/ML/Python/Practice/Scraper/Scraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/git/ML/Python/Practice/Scraper/Scraper.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Steps I took when setting up project:

1. python3 -m venv project_name/venv
2. source project_name/venv/bin/activate
3. python3 -m pip install SomePackage

Confirmation package and dependences were installed:

```
(venv) USERs-MacBook-Pro:Scraper user$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- ---------
certifi    2020.12.5
chardet    4.0.0
idna       2.10
pip        20.2.3
requests   2.25.1
setuptools 49.2.1
urllib3    1.26.2
```

Comment: I guess that `pip` is not linked with `python3.9`. Can you try running `pip --version` and paste the output?

Comment: did you try `pip3 install requests`

Comment: Ran the command `pip --version` and got the following: `pip 20.2.3 from /Users/user/git/ML/Python/Practice/Scraper/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)`

Comment: Ran the command `pip3 install requests` and got the following output: Requirement already satisfied

Comment: That does not seem to be the problem, anything else I can check

Comment: You appear to be running the system python3, and not the venv python3.

Comment: No, that is not the case. My terminal shows `(venv) USERs-MacBook-Pro:Scraper user$` Note the venv

Comment: Yes, but you use the absolute path to system python3.9. Try executing it by just using `python filename` if default python for venv is 3.9 or `python3.9 filename`

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, can you dumb it down for me. I have run the commands and the file is running.

Comment: The correct executable from your venv to use would be `project_name/venv/bin/python3`, you use instead the system one, no wonder the import doesn't resolve. With your venv activated, just run `python /Users/user/git/ML/Python/Practice/Scraper/Scraper.py`, the shell will use the correct executable.

Comment: Ok, it worked. I do not fully understand so I will read the docs. Thanks, @hoefling

Comment: Because sourcing the activation script changes the current shell environment. In particular the `PATH` env var, so the executable from your virtual env will be preferred to any other when running the `python` command. I guess @itroulli described it well; don't forget to upvote the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the absolute path to system Python like that:

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /Users/user/git/ML/Python/Practice/Scraper/Scraper.py
```

you are using system's Python 3.9 and the packages that are installed for that one although you are in a virtual environment.

When creating a virtual environment you are creating a separate environment with the specified python version and all the packages you install with pip are installed to this environment and this python version.

You can better understand that if you run:

```
which python
```

inside your virtual environment.

This will show you the python that is used when you run `python` inside your venv and it's going to be different than

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
```

So, by having installed `requests` using `pip` inside your environment, it is installed in the environments python which is executed when you run just `python`.

To sum up, to use the packages installed inside your venv with `pip` you should run your script (after activating the venv) with:

```
python /Users/user/git/ML/Python/Practice/Scraper/Scraper.py
```